# JavaScript - How can I return the branch of a tree in a node search?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, tree

My data structure will look like this:

```
var tree = [
    {
        id: 1,
        children: []
    }, {
        id: 2,
        children: [
            {
                id: 3,
                children: []
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

There can be any number of nodes or children on one branch.

My goal is to start at the top (root) node, search for a given node and return the branch it's on.

So in the example on Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/PyR3H7mM0vrFyno1l7R5?p=catalogue

I want to search for the node id # 31, so the algorithm will return the array (branch) that 31 is a part of.

I have started the algorithm but if I do it recursively I don't know how to backtrack out again.

```
function traverse(branch) {

  for (var i = 0; i < branch.length; i++) {
    if (branch[i].id == node.id) {
      return branch;
    }
  }

  for (var j = 0; j < branch.length; j++) {
    if (branch[j].children.length > 0) {
      return traverse(branch[j].children);
    }
  }

}

console.log(traverse(tree));
```

For example, if I look down to the last child node without finding a match then I need to backtrack to the parent branch to try the next set of options.

How can I modify my algorithm to backtrack out again?

Comment: What would you like to return if a match is not found? You should only return the result of the recursive call if it found something.

Comment: In my situation a match will always be found because I am going to get the user to click on one of them to kick start the search process.

Comment: Sure, but if you want to make your code recursive, you have to expect that not every branch of your tree will contain a match, so you have to return something in those cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algorithm is very close, you just need to add an `if` statement so that it only returns the recursive result from `traverse` if a match was found:

```
function traverse(branch) {

  for (var i = 0; i < branch.length; i++) {
    if (branch[i].id == node.id) {
      return branch;
    }
  }

  for (var j = 0; j < branch.length; j++) {
    var result = traverse(branch[j].children);
    if (result !== undefined) {
      return result;
    }
  }

  return undefined; // no match found

}

console.log(traverse(tree));
```

Comment: How can I modify the algorithm so it will find multiple matches instead of just one?

Comment: Instead of `return`ing inside the loops, you will need to `push` into an array of `results`, then return the `results` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an temporary variable for the result of the children and exit the loop if the value is truthy.

```
function traverse(branch) {
    var result;
    for (var i = 0; i < branch.length; i++) {
        if (branch[i].id === node.id) {
            return branch;
        }
        if (branch[j].children.length > 0) {
            result = traverse(branch[j].children);
            if (result) {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick to return the branch rather than the node itself:

```
    function traverse(branch) {

        for (var i = 0; i < branch.length; i++) {
            if (branch[i].id == node.id) {
                return branch[i].children;
            }
        }

        for (var j = 0; j < branch.length; j++) {
            var result = traverse(branch[j].children);
            if (result !== null) {
                return result;
            }
        }

        return null; // no match found
    }
```